# No screens found error when starting fresh install of chroot debian wheezy with xfce gui

Tags: debian, xorg, chroot, chrome-os, chrome-book

I am not an experienced Linux user, but have bought a chromebook and am now installing crouton. This is the very first thing I did with the Chromebook, so I don't think I need a powerwash. First I installed the Chrome app 'extension' for the Chrome OS extension. I then downloaded crouton and ran this command:

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r wheezy -t xfce-desktop,extension -n myfirstchroot
```

It then installs Debian wheezy with the xfce gui and some common applications and extension support under the name myfirstchroot.

Then I try to boot it with this command `sudo startxfce4`

Which gives an error `fatal server error: no screens found`

Then if I run `sudo enter-chroot` followed by `Xorg -configure` it gives the error `fatal server error: server is already running for display 0`

I also tried reinstalling xorg with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg` inside the chroot, and tried fresh installs with different gui's after `sudo delete-chroot myfirstchroot`, but the situation was unchanged.

I don't understand what's wrong. There are several posts I find when googling the error `no screens found` but they are all related to situations where a user has a chroot with gui running correctly but then after a crouton update it doesn't anymore. My case is different I think because nothing got updated, it's all a fresh install.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?